# gulp task execution extremely slow

Tags: gulp

My gulp tasks, when combined, are taking a long time to execute. I have a compile task as shown below:

```
gulp.task('compile', function () {
  var tsResult = gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tscConfig.compilerOptions));
  return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['compile']);
```

When I run the above `gulp build` I get the following output:

```
[10:03:24] Starting 'compile'...
[10:03:26] Finished 'compile' after 2.02 s
[10:03:26] Starting 'build'...
[10:03:26] Finished 'build' after 22 μs
```

Then I add in 1 other task (`copy:libs`):

```
gulp.task('copy:libs', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
      'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**',
      'reflect-metadata/temp/Reflect.js',
      'rxjs/**',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      '@angular/**'
    ], {cwd: "node_modules/**"})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/lib'))
});

gulp.task('build', ['compile', 'copy:libs']);
```

Running `gulp build` again, this is the output:

```
[10:03:43] Starting 'compile'...
[10:03:43] Starting 'copy:libs'...
[10:03:54] Finished 'compile' after 11 s
[10:03:56] Finished 'copy:libs' after 12 s
[10:03:56] Starting 'build'...
[10:03:56] Finished 'build' after 24 μs
```

Again, running each of those tasks individually doesn't take long at all. And it doesn't matter what I combine. If I did any of the following:

```
gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'copy:libs']);
gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'compile']);
```

It takes 10+ seconds to complete. Any help is appreciated. If I need to share more code, let me know.